# I want to send data on a hidden input to my validation php page using a php variable as value

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have been triying to do it, i have watch several tutorial and read hundred of pages... im starting to think that what i want to do is impossible and ilogical, even tho its seens like a really simple concept in my head

This is my html/php Code

```
    <?php
  session_start();
  include 'conect.php';

  $consultar = "SELECT * FROM saida";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($link,$consultar);
  $sqlContrato = "SELECT * FROM saida WHERE NumeroContrato = (SELECT MAX(NumeroContrato) FROM saida);";
  $resultado2 = mysqli_query($link,$sqlContrato);


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mota.css"/>

    <title>Mota Saida</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body id="main">
    <header>
    <h1 id="title">
     Mota Saida
    </h1>

  </header>
    <div id="container">
    <p class="hidden">.</p>

    <div id="pae">

      <div id="form-div">


          <form action="saida2.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="child">
              <div class="label-form">

                <label for="numC">Numero de Contrato:</label>

              </div>
              <?php while($vector2=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2)) { ?>
              <div class="input">
                <?php

                       echo $vector2[0]?> 
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="child">   

              <div class="label-form">
                  <label for="nMota">Numero da mota</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                  <?php 
                      $NumerodaMota = $vector2[1];
                     $sqlMota = "SELECT * FROM bike WHERE NumeroMota = $NumerodaMota[0]";
                    $resultado3 = mysqli_query($link,$sqlMota);
                  echo $NumerodaMota;?> 
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="child"> 
              <div class="label-form">
                <label for="dias">Dias</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input">
                <?php echo $vector2[2]?> 

              </div>
          </div>


      <form action="saida2.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="child">
              <div class="label-form">
                <label for="kilometrosS">Kilometros</label>
              </div>
             <div class="input">
              <input type="number" name="numerohidden" hidden value='<?php 
                  $vector2[0] ?>'>
```

In my head this seen to work but only failed to do so....

```
<input type="number" name="numerohidden" hidden value='<?php 
              $vector2[0] ?>'>
```

This is my php/sql code

```
    <?php 
    define('SERVIDOR', 'localhost');
    define('USUARIO', 'root');
    define('BD', 'moto');
    define('PASSWORD', '');

    $link = mysqli_connect(SERVIDOR, USUARIO, PASSWORD, BD) or die("Error de conexion de base de datos");
  if(!mysqli_select_db($link,'moto')){
        echo 'db not selected';
        echo mysqli_erro($link);
    }

    $NumeroContrato = $_POST['numerohidden'];
     echo $NumeroContrato;
```

I am triying to past that number so i can update a sql table

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE saida SET Kilometros= '$Kilometros', NumeroHelmet1 = '$NumeroHelmet1',NumeroHelmet2 = '$NumeroHelmet2',DataSaida = '$DataSaida' ,HoraSaida = '$HoraSaida',DataEntrada = '$DataEntrada',HoraEntrada ='$HoraEntrada',Combustivel = '$Combustivel',Seguro = '$Seguro',ValorSeguro = '$ValorSeguro',Aluger = '$Aluger',Total = '$Total',Funcionaria = '$Funcionaria',Loja = '$Loja',Estado = '$Estado',Ticket = '$Ticket' WHERE NumeroContrato = '$NumeroContrato'" ;
```

I am new to php programing so if you can help me please do.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: numerohidden input doesn't have "echo" in the php part

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: this <input type="number" name="numerohidden" hidden value='<?php $vector2[0] ?>'> should be <input type="number" name="numerohidden" hidden value='<?php echo $vector2[0] ?>'>

Comment: OMG IT WORK NOW THANK U SO MUCH

Comment: That should also be `type="hidden"` NOT `type="number" hidden`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 errors in your code:
1. input type is not "hidden"
2. You have to echo your php variable.

change

```
<input type="number" name="numerohidden" hidden value='<?php 
              $vector2[0] ?>'>
```

To

```
<input type="hidden" name="numerohidden" value='<?php echo $vector2[0] ?>'>
```